# Run Specific Row from examples table in JBEHAVE

Tags: java, bdd, jbehave

Iam running the jbehave scenarios for multiple test data iterations (there are 60 testdata rows )using Example tables.

For some reason the tests are failing for some iterations.

I want to re-rerun only those set of testdata which are failed .

Can anybody please help me on this, i don't want to run the scenarios again for all the testdata rows under Examples table

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new column to your table with `Meta:` and use meta tags to specify which table rows should be executed. For example:

```
Meta: | column1 | column2 |
@test1| value1  | value2  |
@test2| value3  | value4  |
```

and then run your test with a maven run configuration where your goal is:

`clean verify serenity:aggregate -Dmetafilter="+test1"`

this will run only tests with meta filter `@test1`. If you add `-test1` instead, it will run all tests *except* `@test1`.

you can read more here under `Filtering on example scenarios`:
http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-filtering.html